# OR condition in a formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

The below formula helps to Start from ASD and before the slash it prints all the data.

Query:
Now as per the requirement, i need to search for two words with OR condition.
For eg it should either start with ASD or DEF I tried with OR condition but that is not working.
Can someone pls guide in this.

Working Formula:
`=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ASD",A11)),MID(A11,SEARCH("""",A11)+1,SEARCH("/",A11)-1-SEARCH("""",A11)),"")`

With OR Condition(which is not working)
`=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ASD",A11) OR SEARCH("DEF",A11)),MID(A11,SEARCH("""",A11)+1,SEARCH("/",A11)-1-SEARCH("""",A11)),"")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to look like:

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ASD",A11)), ISNUMBER(SEARCH("DEF",A11))),MID(A11,SEARCH("""",A11)+1,SEARCH("/",A11)-1-SEARCH("""",A11)),"")
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the order of the operations in your formula is the issue.

Example:

```
OR – =IF(OR(Something is True, Something else is True), Value if True, Value if False)
```

cf: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-if-with-and-or-and-not-functions-d895f58c-b36c-419e-b1f2-5c193a236d97

My best guess is that your formula should be

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ASD",A11), SEARCH("DEF",A11))),MID(A11,SEARCH("""",A11)+1,SEARCH("/",A11)-1-SEARCH("""",A11)),"")
```

Comment: yeah the same concept , but am getting a pop up like "you have entered too many arguements for this function"

Comment: @ML-1994 The issue with your answer is, that your formula is not working due to a syntax error in the `ISNUMERIC` part. `ISNUMERIC` can only take one argument and you put 2 arguments.

Comment: Yes I know that cause I gave the answer in a way to let him find the solution using the provided documentation... That's the purpose here, the we teach people how to fish and not just simply give them a fish....

Comment: I made an [edit] to your answer to improve the formatting around the pseudocode, but there's a peculiar `OR -` at the beginning that I assume is errant. It doesn't really make sense as part of the description, but it also doesn't make sense as part of the code. I didn't want to fundamentally change your answer, but is confusing at best. Can you [edit] your answer to clarify your intent?